# Mongo geolocation using $near and 2d index not being accurate

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongoose, geospatial

I've written an application that finds local establishments and delivers them via a RESTful API. My stack is: express, express-resource and mongoose. Here is a sample of my model:

```
var PlaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        geolocation: {
            lat: Number,
            lng: Number
        },
        address: {
            type: String
        }
    }
);
PlaceSchema.index({
    geolocation: '2d'
});
```

I've checked a few times and my lon/lat values are being correctly stored in the db, so there aren't any data errors.

Then I run the query to grab the data with the specific query values:

```
mongoose.connection.db.executeDbCommand(
    {
        geoNear: 'places',
        near: [
            parseFloat(req.body.lat),
            parseFloat(req.body.lng)
        ],
        num: limit,
        query: {
            // Some additional queries that
            // don't impact the geo results.
        },
        spherical: true,
        distanceMultiplier: 6371, // converting results to km
        maxDistance: distance / 6371,
    },
    function(err, result)
    {
        res.send(200, {
            status: true,
            data:   theaters
        });
    }
);
```

There are a few issues with the results that it's returning: a) the calculation in km is *really* wrong. In most cases there's a 6-7km difference, but it varies, b) places that are closer are appearing farther than other places.

I'm using the direct mongoose query because it will return the calculated distance (which I require for my API returns). Switching to the mongoose find method apparently wouldn't let me gain access to this data.

Wondering if my index is perhaps wrong? Should it be 2dsphere instead? The documentation in that regard is slightly confusing, but most of the examples I see use just 2d.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No matter what type of geospatial indexing you use in MongoDB, you always must store longitude first and then latitude.

From http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/#store-points-on-a-2d-plane and multiple other places in the docs:

> Whether as an array or document, if you use longitude and latitude,
>   store coordinates in this order: **longitude, latitude.**

Comment: And the only other suggestion is to try this in the command line first before trying it in code.Which version of MongoDB are you using, this would matter a lot in terms of correct answer.

Comment: The version would not matter. Coordinates in MongoDB are always specified longitude first.

Comment: Doesn't have to be in version 2.2 and before - if you just use a 2d index

Comment: No, 2.4 is compatible with 2d indexes - it also provides 2dsphere indexes which *also* require the same long/lat order.

Comment: Yes but 2.2 does not REQUIRE that order unless you are doing sphere calcs.

Comment: Considering that you would then be able to store latitude values larger than 90 (since you're storing them where MongoDB expects longitude), you might also check the note on the same page: "Important The default boundaries allow applications to insert documents with invalid latitudes greater than 90 or less than -90. The behavior of geospatial queries with such invalid points is not defined."

Comment: We are facing this problem.One piece of code stores location in lat, lng order and another piece of code should stores them in lng, lat order. The fix is to reorder all the locations in lng,lat order .Is there a way in which I can query only those documents which have been stored in the incorrect order ?