# Can't extract geo keys (nodejs and mongo)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geolocation, database

I am working with nodejs (expres framwork) and mongodb with mongoose. And I am trying to save the geolocation coordinates to my db.

This is how my schema looks like:

```
//defining a schema
var TopicSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   topicTitle: String,
   topicDescription: String,
   topicDateCreated: { 
      type: Date, 
      default: Date.now 
   },
   fbId: String,
   twId: String,
   location: {
      type: {
        type : String
      },
   coordinates: [Number]
  }
});

TopicSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
var Topic = restful.model('topic', TopicSchema);
Topic.methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);
Topic.register(app, '/data');
```

Via socket.io I pass the data to the server. The server receives the data but upon saving it I get the following error:

```
MongoError: Can't extract geo keys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

`var coordinates =  LON + ", " + LAT;`

What happens here is that you combine the two numbers with a string and your `coordinates` becomes a string.
You schema is defined as an array of location points with `[Number]`. Sending your `coordinates` as a string will violate your schema definition.

To solve your error create an array of geo points like e.g. `var coordinates = [LON, LAT];`

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb uses a longitude-latitude system to store a geolocation index. This coordinates are in float values, but you put them a Number to use. Try following Scheme:

```
var TopicSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   topicTitle: String,
   topicDescription: String,
   topicDateCreated: { 
      type: Date, 
      default: Date.now 
   },
   fbId: String,
   twId: String,
   location: {
      type: {
        type : String
      },
   coordinates: [ ]
  }
});
```

Other examples you can see from this [repo](https://github.com/tmlbl/mongoose-geolocation-example) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635955/mongo-geolocation-using-near-and-2d-index-not-being-accurate)

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#btnPostTopic").on("click", function(e)
            {
                //get the value of the inputfields and textarea
                var title = $('#TopicTitle').val();
                var description = $('#TopicDescription').val();
                var LON = parseFloat($('#longitude').val());
                var LAT = parseFloat($('#latitude').val());

                var coordinates =  LON + ", " + LAT; 
                console.log("COORDINATES are " + coordinates); 

                var resultLocalStorageFB = document.getElementById("resultFB");
                var resultLocalStorageTW = document.getElementById("resultTW");
                resultLocalStorageFB.value = localStorage.getItem("useridfb");
                resultLocalStorageTW.value = localStorage.getItem("useridtw");
                console.log(resultLocalStorageFB);
                console.log(resultLocalStorageTW);

                var FbId = $('#resultFB').val();
                var TWId = $('#resultTW').val();
                console.log('Fb Id: ' + FbId);
                console.log('TW Id: ' + TWId);

                var Point = "Point";

                result = { 
                    "topicTitle": title, 
                    "topicDescription": description, 
                    "fbId": FbId,
                    "twId": TWId,
                    "location": {
                        "type": Point,
                        coordinates 
                    }    
                };
                console.log("Values of inputfield & textarea: " + result);

                //makes the connection to the server and send the data 
                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
                socket.emit('sendTopic', result);   
                //console.log("Gets send: " + result);
            });

        });
```